# REST - pattern to naming resources

Tags: rest

I'm developing several resources REST and i was wondering what is the best practice to naming it when you have cases like:

- Insert a new configuration ( 1 'configuration' = 1 'file' ) for a client;
- Return a list of files from a specific client ( return all )
- Return a specific file from a specific client ( return all )

I've created those URI's:

- POST /api/file/dbconfig/client/{clientId}
- GET /api/file/client/:clientId
- GET /api/file/:fileId/client/:clientId

For me, this is not legible but i don't know if i should switch it to something like:

- POST /api/configuration/{clientId}/
- GET /api/configuration/{clientId}/files
- GET /api/configuration/{clientId}/{fileId}

I don't believe that i need a resource called **File** because a "File" is a part of Configuration.

What's your opinion about my resource naming?

Comment: If a file is part of a configuration, where is the configuration in 'Return a specific file from a specific client'? Can you address the file without addressing the configuration?

Comment: Yes, i just need the fileId and clientId to retrieve..i've named Configuration as a File but i it don't make sense because it's not a File..it's an information about a Configuration ( FileConfiguration )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this scheme.

```
POST /api/clients/{clientId}/configurations
```

creates a new configuration for the client.

```
GET /api/clients/{clientId}/configurations
```

returns the list of configurations for the client.

```
GET /api/clients/{clientId}/configurations/{configurationId}
```

returns a configuration for the client.

Some notes:

- I'd name collection resources in the plural form: `clients`, `configurations`. To `GET` such a resource means to get a list of all resources.
- I'd order the URL path parts in such a way, that the outer resource (user) comes first and the inner resource (configuration) comes last:  `/api/clients/{clientId}/configurations/{configurationId}`.

Comment: Do you mean query parameters? Yes, it is common practice to use them to filter a collection resource. For example, `/api/aclients/123/configurations?valid=true` could be used to get all valid configurations for client `123`. Remember that query parameters are part of the URL that identifies a unique resource. Don't use query parameters to transfer what should be part of a `POST` body.